# Looking for a book in group theory similar to Nathan Jacobson's style

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

Can anyone recommend some books on group theory which is similar to Nathan Jacobson's style of writing (verbose/paragraph style)?

Comment: This is quite broad, as group theory is enormous, what are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

The classical, very interesting book I would say are

> Theory of Groups (vol. I , II) - A. G. Kurosh.

Other elementary or modern books are

> Topics in Group Theory - Geoff Smith, Olga Tabachnikova.
>
> Finite Group Theory - I. Martin Isaacs.